# Launch program from vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to launch a program called WebDrive from a vbscript but I cant get the syntax right to launch the program with a number of parameters; currently run from a batch file:

```
start /wait /D "c:\program files\webdrive" webdrive.exe /s:"syd-ftp.thruinc.net"
```

My base code is:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("cscript.Shell")
objShell.Run start /wait /D c:\program files\webdrive webdrive.exe /s:"syd-ftp.thruinc.net"""
Set objShell = Nothing
```

I have read a number of posts on this site relating to this topic but I cant seem to get the quotes right, for example:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("cscript.Shell")
objShell.Run "start /wait /D ""c:\program files\webdrive"" webdrive.exe /s:"""syd-ftp.thruinc.net"""
Set objShell = Nothing
```

Any advice would be great.

Regards

Martin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
objShell.Run "start /wait /D ""c:\program files\webdrive"" webdrive.exe /s:"""syd-ftp.thruinc.net"""
                                                                           ^
```

Remove one of the double quote here!

You can echo out the command first to check whether it is in correct quote or not

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
'WScript.Echo "start /wait /D ""c:\program files\webdrive"" webdrive.exe /s:""syd-ftp.thruinc.net"""
objShell.Run "start /wait /D ""c:\program files\webdrive"" webdrive.exe /s:""syd-ftp.thruinc.net"""
Set objShell = Nothing
```

I use `WScript.Shell` to create `objShell` instead of `cscript.shell`. It seems ok.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a generic way to launch using VBScript:

CONNECT:

`Set objShell = CreateObject("WdScript.Shell") 
objShell.Run """C:\Program Files\WebDrive\webdrive.exe"" /s:""site""" 
Set objShell = Nothing`

DISCONNECT:

`Set objShell = CreateObject("WdScript.Shell") 
objShell.Run """C:\Program Files\WebDrive\webdrive.exe"" W: /d" 
Set objShell = Nothing`

The site part of it is dependent on your particular site profile, and the W:
is dependent on the drive letter you selected to use. Whatever drive letter you chose should go where the W is.

Specifically for this instance, you could:

CONNECT:

`Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
objShell.Run """C:\Program Files\WebDrive\webdrive.exe"" /s:""syd-ftp.thruinc.net""" 
Set objShell = Nothing`

DISCONNECT:

`Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
objShell.Run """C:\Program Files\WebDrive\webdrive.exe"" W: /d" 
Set objShell = Nothing`