# How do I fix a "SCRIPT424: Object required: 'Environment'" in Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, web-applications, vbscript

I'm trying to launch an IIS webapp in a new browser session, I'd prefer cross platform, but IE only is ok; I asked on the [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/f1e6bc97-22ae-4731-a509-8e646625826a/internet-explorer-get-new-sessions-programatically?forum=iewebdevelopment) and they recommended code similar to the following, but it fails to find the Environment variable and MSFT has not gotten back to me in 2 days.

Do I need to import something? Is there a good vbscript tutorial?

```
<script type="text/vbscript">
        function VBLaunch(ByVal url)
            ProductDir= Environment.value("ProductDir")
            IF (Instr(1,ProductDir,"(x86)"))>0 then
                SystemUtil.Run "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE", "-noframemerging " &  URL'  Launch Internet explorer and enter given URL
            Else
                SystemUtil.Run "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE","-noframemerging " & URL'  Launch Internet explorer and enter given URL
            End if
        end function
</script>
```

This may be an instance of the XY problem, so if there is a better way short of rewriting most of the app to launch an IIS webapp so it gets a different Session cookie as the current tab I would be fine with it.

Comment: That script will never run in its current form *(that's the problem with people supplying code snippets without any clarification of what it does or whether its even been tested)*. The code provided is a form of VBScript but for use inside [tag:qtp] / [tag:hp-uft] and will not work standalone, you could replace the QTP specific commands with WScript ones which will allow you to start IE with the request command line switches. [Here is a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28379432/692942) that deals with running a problem via VBScript.

Comment: Thanks, that led me down the right path and I wrote my eventual solution as the answer; if you'd prefer you could rewrite your comment as an answer and I'll just unaccept mine and choose yours instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Lankymart who pointed out the VBscript MSFT gave me was using some sort of test framework, I looked around and eventually came up with this

```
<script type="text/vbscript">
 function VBLaunch(ByVal url)

     Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
     WshShell.Run "iexplore.exe " & url

 end function
</script>
```

This does work, but requires setting a low security level and allowing activex; so I would not recommend this approach.